# A 5 points rating formula in SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
       RATING
[  id -  pid = rate]
[  1  -   1  -  5  ]
[  2  -   1  -  5  ]
[  3  -   1  -  4  ]
[  4  -   1  -  1  ]
[  5  -   1  -  1  ]

WHERE pid = 1;
$r5 = 10;
$r4 = 4;
$r3 = 0;
$r2 = 0;
$r1 = 2;
$tt = 16;
```

from this table i'm trying to make this mathematical formula

```
($r5*5 + $r4*4 + $r3*3 + $r2*2 + $r1) / $tt
```

instead of calling all the values into array and calculating it, How can i do inside the query itself? In which one is actually faster and the most efficient for the website?

Comment: Your formula suggests that the values are ordered in some way or that you have a way of identifying which-is-which.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so your question does not have enough information to answer the question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff So it is impossible to do it through SQL because i have no way to identify the *x constants?

Comment: After modifying the question to include a unique id, it is clearly possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following solution:

```
SELECT pid,
    (((SUM(CASE WHEN rate = 5 THEN 5 ELSE 0 END) * 5) +
    (SUM(CASE WHEN rate = 4 THEN 4 ELSE 0 END) * 4) +
    (SUM(CASE WHEN rate = 3 THEN 3 ELSE 0 END) * 3) +
    (SUM(CASE WHEN rate = 2 THEN 2 ELSE 0 END) * 2) +
    (SUM(CASE WHEN rate = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1)) / SUM(rate)) AS c_rate
FROM table_name
WHERE pid = 1
GROUP BY pid
```

To format your output without rounding the result you can use [`TRUNCATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_truncate). You can also use [`ROUND`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round) if the result should be rounded and truncated.

**solution using `TRUNCATE`:**

```
SELECT pid,
    TRUNCATE((((SUM(CASE WHEN rate = 5 THEN 5 ELSE 0 END) * 5) +
    (SUM(CASE WHEN rate = 4 THEN 4 ELSE 0 END) * 4) +
    (SUM(CASE WHEN rate = 3 THEN 3 ELSE 0 END) * 3) +
    (SUM(CASE WHEN rate = 2 THEN 2 ELSE 0 END) * 2) +
    (SUM(CASE WHEN rate = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1)) / SUM(rate)), 1) AS c_rate
FROM table_name
WHERE pid = 1
GROUP BY pid
```

**solution using `ROUND`:**

```
SELECT pid,
    ROUND((((SUM(CASE WHEN rate = 5 THEN 5 ELSE 0 END) * 5) +
    (SUM(CASE WHEN rate = 4 THEN 4 ELSE 0 END) * 4) +
    (SUM(CASE WHEN rate = 3 THEN 3 ELSE 0 END) * 3) +
    (SUM(CASE WHEN rate = 2 THEN 2 ELSE 0 END) * 2) +
    (SUM(CASE WHEN rate = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1)) / SUM(rate)), 1) AS c_rate
FROM table_name
WHERE pid = 1
GROUP BY pid
```

Comment: i've wrapped the entire formula in `(formula) AS rate` but for the table i showed as example if i did `echo $row['rate'];` it shows me `1.0000` instead of `4.25`, Did i wrap it wrong?

Comment: looks fine (see my update too). try another name not exist in your table...

Comment: Still the same problem, I actually have some of my `pid` named using letters and words Instead of numbers, Would that affect the query? like `WHERE id = title-post`

Comment: which database? MySQL, MSSQL, another?

Comment: MySQL as i know, MariaDB.

Comment: Try again removing the `rate` from `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Can i set the values instead of `4.2500` to `4.25` or `4.2` using SQL too?

Comment: Where do i put it exactly? I tried to put it after the `SELECT` but didn't work.